# Decoder Simulation Results are incorrect

Tags: vhdl, decoder

I was trying to design a simple address decoder using VHDL. The simulation results are wrong. I am sharing the code below for your reference.
In my design, I want to set a bit in my output corresponding to my input

```
entity Decoder is
  generic (
    NUM_BITS : integer :=3
    );
  Port (
    a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (NUM_BITS -1 downto 0);
    ena : in STD_LOGIC;
    b : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ((2**NUM_BITS)-1 downto 0)
    );
end Decoder;

architecture Behavioral of Decoder is
begin
  process(ena)
  begin
    if(ena ='0') then
      b <= (others => '0');
    else
      b(to_integer(unsigned(a))) <= '1';
    end if;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I am also sharing my simulation results for additional reference
[image]

Comment: Did you try to add `a` to the sensitivity list of the process?

Comment: Even fixing @thebusybee 's problem, there's another one ... you need to ensure ONLY the decoded bit becomes active.

Comment: That solved part of my problem, thanks to busy bee.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a to the sensitivity list and removing the if statement makes this code works perfectly.
Once again thanks for your time.

```
process(ena,a)
begin

b <= (others => '0');

b(to_integer(unsigned(a))) <= '1';



end process;
```

Comment: What is "ena" supposed to do then?

Comment: I think you forgot the if statements

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote in your question is not likely to work as you expect, as you are inferring a latch (which is almost never a good design, and usually unintentional, as I suspect it was here). The latch is due to the fact that your process is retaining your previously set bits.

Do you really want your "decoder" to have memory? If so, I would call it something other than "decoder", and would use a clock.

Note that in your posted answer `ena` doesn't do anything. It *may* trick your simulator into entering the process block (which maybe is ok, if that's all you want), but it will synthesize out.

The code in your question has this RTL:
[image: OP RTL]

Here's what I would suggest:

- Get rid of the process. Not needed.
- Use `ena` as a mux select
- When `ena` is 0, set your output `b` to 0
- Otherwise, shift a 1 to the appropriate bit

Something like this:

```
architecture Behavioral of Decoder is
begin

    with ena select
        b <= (others => '0') when '0',
             std_logic_vector(shift_left(to_unsigned(1, 2**NUM_BITS), to_integer(unsigned(a)))) when others;

end Behavioral;
```

The RTL of this looks like:
[image: shift and mux]

Notice no latch; just a shift and a mux.

Here's the sim:
[image: sim]

---

*edit* 
The text above has been edited. I originally misread the code you posted in your **answer**; there is no implied latch there. The text above applies to the original code in your **question**. If you prefer to stick with using a process (for some reason), you could make your code work as:

(though this is 7 lines, as opposed to the 3 I suggest above)

```
process(a, ena)
begin
    b <= (others => '0');
    if ena = '1' then
        b(to_integer(unsigned(a))) <= '1';
    end if;
end process;
```